# Can webClient be mocked if it's initialised in PostConstruct method?

Tags: spring, mocking, mockito, spring-test

I have a class with private WebClient which is initialised via PostConstruct.
I would like to mock it to not call real endpoints, but I have't got any idea how I can create mock for this object. As it't not initialised via a field or a constructor.
Can anyone advise how to it can be mocked without using reflection?
Thank you.

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

  private final ServiceB serviceB;

  private WebClient webClient;

  @PostConstruct
  public void init() {

    this.webClient = WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(new HttpClient()))
        .build();
  }

  @Override
  public String request(String body) {
    return this.requestString(body)
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
  }

  public WebClient.ResponseSpec requestString(String body) {

    return webClient
        .post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("/test/{id}/")
            .build(1))
        .bodyValue(body)
        .retrieve();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get rid of the PostContruct initialization and
just create a WebClient bean and let spring to inject it in  your class:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeConfig {


    @Bean
   public WebClient webClient() {
        WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(new HttpClient()))
        .build();
   }
}
```

So, your class would look like this after refactoring, now you can mock them easily:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

  private final ServiceB serviceB;

  private final WebClient webClient;

  @Override
  public String request(String body) {
    return this.requestString(body)
        .bodyToMono(String.class)
        .block();
  }

  public WebClient.ResponseSpec requestString(String body) {

    return webClient
        .post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder
            .path("/test/{id}/")
            .build(1))
        .bodyValue(body)
        .retrieve();
  }
}
```

Comment: Good idea. @Boldi Istvan I have many web clients e.g. webClientA, webClientB.
Is it considered normal/good practice to store all of them in a single Configuration class?

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks, Nothing wrong having all webClient in a single configuration class.